# Can't remove lock from python leveldb database

Tags: python, database, leveldb

I'm working with a leveldb database (the leveldb wrapper, not plyvel); I ran a few test Put/Get/Delete operations on the database and everything was okay.  (If it's relevant, I was accessing the database from 2 separate Python scripts.)  Then I tried to make another database within a Python file that was already accessing the first database and I got this error:

```
leveldb.LevelDBError: IO error: lock ./states/LOCK: already held by process
```

So far I've tried deleting the database, uninstalling and reinstalling leveldb, deleting the LOCK file within the database, restarting my computer, and [whatever this code snippet is](https://github.com/dsindex/blog/wiki/%5Bpython%5D-LevelDB).  I'm kind of at my wits' end now; any advice you can offer would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

per design, leveldb databases can only be held open by a single process at the time.